# Wrong answer in rtmvnorm() in R while sampling truncated normal

Tags: r, covariance, normal-distribution, truncated

I am unable to find why I am not getting the right correlation structure after sampling.

I am using the `rtmvnorm` in R from `tmvtnorm` package. I am using example 1 provided in the [pdf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmvtnorm/tmvtnorm.pdf) for the section of this function.

```
sigma <- matrix(c(4,2,2,3), ncol=2)
x <- rtmvnorm(n=500, mean=c(1,2), sigma=sigma, upper=c(1,0))
```

when I am using the above to find the `cor(x)` and `cov2cor(sigma)` my results appear very different.

```
> cor(x)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.2126776
#[2,] 0.2126776 1.0000000

> cov2cor(sigma)
#          [,1]      [,2]
#[1,] 1.0000000 0.5773503
#[2,] 0.5773503 1.0000000
```

My objective is to generate truncated normal samples with a covariance structure.

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  9.0  3.6
[2,]  3.6 16.0
```

Maybe I am missing something here. Can someone explain it to me in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you surprised? `cov2cor(sigma)` is the correlation matrix for non-truncated normal, while `cor(x)` is the correlation matrix for truncated normal. Of course they are not the same. Similarly, `cov(x)` is different from `sigma`.

Do you want to compare `cov2cor(cov(x))` and `cor(x)`? That will be the same.

Comment: Thanks @Li, can you suggest what is the best way to then generate random numbers using a covariance structure of a truncated normal (say `sigma`) such that my `cor(x)` is same as correlation structure of `sigma`. I have provided an example above in my question.

Comment: @Li yes, I read the documentation, it uses a non-truncated normal and uses algorithm to discard value out of range.

Comment: @Li, Thanks, I understand it now. I was trying to re-create a simulation example, where it says that 1) Demands are truncated normal RVs at `0.2xmean and 1.8xmean`2)They are positively correlated with a correlation coefficient of 0.3. 3)Authors are estimating the expected demand by sampling. So, i was wondering if there is a method to get the cor(x) to a specific number. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @vivek consider accepting Zheyuan's answer and perhaps up-voting it if you found it satisfactory

Comment: @ZheyuanLi sure. I will write in a new question!